# Export Database as Scripts; Sequences not set correctly

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms, sql-server-2014, sql-server-2016

I want to take a Database from a SQLServer 2016 and set it up on a 2014 server on a clients' site.

In SSMS I select Tasks => Generate scripts... and get a SQL file containing all `CREATE TABLE` statements and the like.

I'm under the impression that the sequences are not generated correctly. The sequences are in use and have current values larger than one. However, every `CREATE SEQUENCE` statement has a `START WITH 1` clause.

Can I set somehow, that the sequences get a start value according to the their cuurenty value?

Comment: No, it is not an option. You get the definition of the sequence; it does not "adjust" that definition for current usage. The same thing happens with an identity column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using system tables (`sys.sequences` in this case) you can generate a script that alters the current value of all your sequences.

More info on `sys.sequences` system table can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-sequences-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

First of all run the following script on your **SQL Server 2016** database:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(max)=''

SELECT @sql = @sql + ' ALTER SEQUENCE ' + [name] 
                   + ' RESTART WITH '+ cast ([current_value] AS NVARCHAR(max)) 
                   + CHAR(10) + CHAR(13)    
FROM sys.sequences

PRINT @sql
```

The output should be a list of `ALTER SEQUENCE` statements that contain the current values for all your sequences; you can now add this statements at the end of the scripts you generated from SSMS.

For example, in my test DB this is the result of the previous script:

[image]

Comment: This works nicely. I just wish, SSMS would do it by itself.

Answer (score 1):

The answer by Andrea is not entirely correct.  The `current_value` of `sys.sequences` contains the value that was already handed out previously.  The sequence should start at the next `increment` value. Some extra casting is needed because the values are stored as `sql_variant`.

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(max)=''

SELECT @sql = @sql + N' ALTER SEQUENCE ' + s.name + N'.' +sq.name 
                   + N' RESTART WITH '+ cast (cast(sq.current_value as bigint) + cast(sq.increment as bigint) AS NVARCHAR(20))
                   + CHAR(10) + CHAR(13)    
FROM sys.sequences sq
join sys.schemas s on s.schema_id = sq.schema_id

PRINT @sql
```